# how to use 'select limit 1' in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use this code:
`select id from categories where hotel_id=4 limit 1`

I am new in rails. How do i use `activerecord` in controller to achieve the same result as the above code.
I already have `hotel_id` in `params` in my controller.

Answer (score 4):

Try in your controller this:

```
@category = Category.where(:hotel_id => 4).limit(1)
```

**OR**

```
@category = Category.where(:hotel_id => 4)
```

It will return all the data from categories table which has `hotel_id` as `4`
You can check it by write this line next to above code.

```
abort @category.inspect  # to check in browser what does this object contains
```

If you want first data from the object then you can write `@category.first` same as for last entry `@category.last` after first line..

---

If you need only one first match record then you can use **`find_by`**

```
@category = Category.find_by(:hotel_id => 4)
```

Comment: this will give me all the record but i need only the first record.i.e how do i set `limit 1`

Comment: `@category = Category.where(:hotel_id => 4).limit(1)`  `@menus2=Menu.where(:category_id=> @category).sorted `             i am getting error like:     `Mysql2::Error: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery': SELECT `menus`.* FROM `menus`  WHERE `menus`.`category_id` IN (SELECT  `categories`.`id` FROM `categories`  WHERE `categories`.`hotel_id` = 4 LIMIT 1)  ORDER BY menus.menu_item_name ASC'

Comment: after `@category = Category.where(:hotel_id => 4).limit(1)`  what you get in `@category` object?

Comment: I think you are trying to find Menu with result's category id..in this case try `@category = Category.where(:hotel_id => 4).limit(1)` `@menus2=Menu.where(:category_id=> @category.id).sorted `

Comment: Show us your relations of model

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.limit(1)` or `.first` or `.last`

```
Model.where(hotel_id: 4).limit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The right answer would be using `limit(1)` [reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset)

<del>Using `first` or `last` actually runs the whole query then returns the first element only, would perform badly if the result set is large.</del>

<del>So just stick with `limit`</del>

**EDIT**:

I just checked and i found that using `first` and `last` do actually add `limit` statement to the query, so I guess they are also just as correct as `limit(1)`